# How to draw a square in C with different symbols and diagonals?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Guys i'm pretty stuck here. I'm trying to learn c and create some very basic code which asks the user to insert a number. Then, this number enters the following formula : 2x+1, then I want it to print a hollow square pattern with a different symbol for rows and columns, and add a + in the corners, diagonals, and a "X" in the middle.

I'm stuck in the very very beginning of the code. I don't know where should I even start. I mean I can't even learn how to make different symbols for the rows and  columns.

I'm trying to learn and study it for 3 hours already, watched 20 different YouTube videos and read 20 different coding guides. 
It's so frustrating..

Thanks.

I'm attaching a picture of my code & my output, and the desired output on the right.[image]

the code itself:

```
int size;
    printf("Please enter a number that will define  the size of the square: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    size = 2 * size + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size-2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= size-2; j++) {
            if (j == 1 || j == size - 1) {
                printf("|");
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
            if (i==1 || i==size-2){
                    printf("-");
                }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify which language you're using? C#, C, or C++?

Comment: What's with the tags? This is pretty clearly C code yet you mention C# both in the title and the question.

Comment: You right guys, sorry for the wrong info! I'm too tired :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int size;
    printf("Please enter a number that will define  the size of the square: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    size = 2 * size + 1;

    const char *spaces="                                         "; 
    const char *dashes="-----------------------------------------";

    printf("+%.*s+\n", size, dashes);
    for(int i=1; i<size/2+1; ++i)
    {
        printf("|%.*s\\%.*s/%.*s|\n", i-1, spaces, size-2*i, spaces,i-1, spaces);
    }

    printf("|%.*sX%.*s|\n", size/2, spaces, size/2, spaces);

    for(int i=size/2+1; i<size; ++i)
    {
        printf("|%.*s/%.*s\\%.*s|\n", size-i-1, spaces, 2*(i-size/2)-1, spaces, size-i-1, spaces);
    }
    printf("+%.*s+\n", size, dashes);

    return 0;
}
```

## Example Run:

```
Please enter a number that will define  the size of the square: 8

Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4568KB
    +-----------------+
    |\               /|
    | \             / |
    |  \           /  |
    |   \         /   |
    |    \       /    |
    |     \     /     |
    |      \   /      |
    |       \ /       |
    |        X        |
    |       / \       |
    |      /   \      |
    |     /     \     |
    |    /       \    |
    |   /         \   |
    |  /           \  |
    | /             \ |
    |/               \|
    +-----------------+
```

Comment: thanks alot. Is there a away to make it through without memset? Just the basic futures?

Comment: Thanks again brother, I appreciate it! When I try to use your code, it gives me an error: "A value of type “const char*” cannot be used to initialize an entity of type “char *” " Can't we just define spaces and dashes as simple char or something? Because I want to try this also without any arrays..

Comment: Giving a full solution to a homework problem is really not the intention of this site, and you should know this very well.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture, @EugeneSh.(Rep 13,534)... I answered it because its a fun/interesting little program.  If OP wants to cheat off me, that is his problem.  ***NO*** teacher will believe that this code was written by a new student.